# jmeter view result tree Response data store in CSV?

Tags: load-testing

[image]

I want to store issuedid in csv.
is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which produces the above output
2. Configure it as follows:

   - "Names of created variables" - anything meaningful, i.e. `issuedid`
   - "JSON Path Expressions" - `$.issuedid`
3. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   sample_variables=issuedid
   ```
4. Next time you [run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t your.test.jmx -l result.csv
   ```

   You will see an extra column in the `result.csv` file holding the value of the `issuedid`

References:

- [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)